# How to duplicate a website?

Tags: migration, installation

I work for a UK company who are looking to expand to the US market. We need to create a duplicate (US version) of our Wordpress website to redirect US customers to. We are seeking some guidance in how to best execute this. Preferably, we are looking for an individual with some experience in creating a duplicate Wordpress site for a different country/territory to work with.

[image]

The strategy will be to create a site map for each to achieve better rankings in the US. Any advice will be appreciated. Get in touch for more details if you have experience in implementing this and are interested in working with us. P.S we have WPML installed.

Comment: As you might already be aware, just duplicating the content will be spotted by search engines, so they are likely not to rank the US version at all (given than they'll know the UK version existed first, and will thus tend to continue ranking it). It's best to create two completely unique sites and link them if visitors may wish to visit both. If you don't have the manpower to maintain that much content, then at least make sure to set `hreflang` tags on both sites. This will tell search engines "The English - UK version is at this URL, and an English - US version is at this other URL."

Comment: By 'completely unique', are you also referring to the content and domain? We have begun the process of duplicating everything by adding /us to the URL's. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, completely unique means the content and the code. Crawlers are good at spotting very similar content and also very similar codebases such as the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate your website easily via "**All-in-One WP Migration**" plugin available online. Here is the link for that https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

And for indexing your website as per geographical location you can do that in 3 different ways via HTML tags, HTTP headers and Sitemap. More details you can read over here.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077